# Why s3a performance is Much lower than what I benchmark with cosbench?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3

I use the locally built object storage service (which supports the S3 interface) and run in the same computer room as the Hadoop cluster.

When I use the centos server running Hadoop to execute cosbench to test the object storage service, the bandwidth can reach 2G/s.

After I modified hadoop's core-site.xml file to change default fs to S3a, I tried to use TestDFSIO to test IO performance, and I was puzzled to find that the results were much slower than expected(about 200Mb/s).

So I wonder if there is any tuning plan that I can refer to?

Thanks.

Comment: Please Edit your question to provide more details. For example, how are you measuring the performance? What results make you think it is bad? Is the Hadoop cluster running on AWS, or on-premises with a network connection to S3? How big is the data you are wanting to process? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for my English, I wish I had made myself clear.